# I need advise on if I should rebuild my index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

I have a SQL Server 2008 Standard server on full mirror (safety). I reorganize all indexes weekly. I am looking into rebuilding a few indexes to improve performance. I ran `DBCC SHOWCONTIG` on my largest, most accessed table and got the following results.

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG scanning 'MYTABLE' table...
Table: 'MYTABLE' (12345678); index ID: 1, database ID: 7
TABLE level scan performed.
- Pages Scanned................................: 738663
- Extents Scanned..............................: 92661
- Extent Switches..............................: 92720
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 8.0
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 99.58% [92333:92721]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 0.35%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 41.58%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 467.9
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 94.22%
```

Would rebuilding the index make sense on this table? Would there be any benefits to doing so? I ask because this entails downtime and I am not sure if it is necessary. Plus, the extra log size due to the index could effect the mirror.